# Setting the active rout manually in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using router link for navigation but it is not reloading the page. I need the page be reloaded so i changed router link to href and it is not working fine. But now routerLinkActive directive is not working and the active page is not highlighted. Is there any way to set the active link manually in angular ?

```
<li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/movieCategory']"><i class="icon-film"></i> {{'movieCategory.title'|translate}}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/mediaChannel']"><i class="icon-control-play"></i> {{'mediaChannel.title'|translate}}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/game']"><i class="icon-game-controller"></i> {{'game.title'|translate}}</a>
                </li>
```

i have changed the link to

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" href="/game"><i class="icon-game-controller"></i> {{'game.title'|translate}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reloaded". Usually one doesn't want a single page application to be reloaded. Angular routing is not supposed to work with `<a href="...">`. You can use `router.nativate(...)` in TypeScript code instead.

Comment: :) that`s true, But in my case i have a main Game component and 2 components connected to it (List and Crud). These two components are activated using a pageStatus variable in the main Game component. (So they both operate under url "/game". Therefore when i click the [routerLink]="['/game']" nothing happens. I need to see the list component when it is clicked..

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's enough information. I'd suggest you create a reproduction using Plunker or https://stackblitz.com/